# Recursive function is returning error message

Tags: r, function, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that will do matrix multiplication `n` times.

My code is the following:

```
R <- function(P, n){

  R(P, n-1) %*% P

}
```

I would expect when this function is called with `n = 3` to perform

```
(P %*% P) %*% P.
```

Using an example:

```
> P
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.6  0.1  0.3
[2,]  0.2  0.7  0.1
[3,]  0.3  0.3  0.4
```

However when I call the function I get an error message.

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>   Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Could you explain to me why the function does not work and how the code should be amended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recursive function should have a threshold at which point the recursive calls will stop. Your defined function `R` does not have this condition as the triggered error also mentions that

> evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion

So,

```
R <- function(P, n){
    if (n==1) return(P)
    R(P, n-1) %*% P 
}
```

should solve your problem. Given your example:

```
r1 <- (P %*% P) %*% P
r2 <- R(P,3)
all(r1==r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: OP's data: `P <- structure(c(0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L))`